# Notepad++ - Replace all $_POST elements that don't already contain strip_tags()

Tags: php, search, replace, notepad++

Is it in any way possible to replace all single PHP $_POST['diffentOnEachPage'] elements with strip_tags($_POST['diffentOnEachPage'])

Around 50% of my $_POST elements already contain strip_tags() but some don't.

What would be the best way to approach this without finding each one and adding strip_tags() individually? - Ideally using Notepad++

Comment: Perhaps you could use the occasion to *remove* all those `strip_tags()` calls. It's one of the most misused PHP functions ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate way would be to remove it from everywhere and just do

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
   $_POST[$key] = strip_tags($value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have occurrences of strip_tags($_POST['baz']) you need to be careful not to add strip_tags to those.  To do this you'll want to do negative lookbehind for 'strip_tags' and only replace the remaining instances.

Another catch - $_POST['foo'] wrapped inside a different function - you'll want to preserve the trailing ) when wrapping.

This should do the trick. I'm sure this can break in a number of other ways, but someone smarter than me can fix that :)

I tested this on Notepad++ 6.5.1.

**Find what:**

```
(?<!strip_tags\()(\$_POST\['.*'\])
```

**Replace with:**

```
strip_tags\((\1)\)
```

**Input:**

```
$_POST['foo']
strip_tags($_POST['baz'])
another_function($_POST['bar'])
```

**Output:**

```
strip_tags($_POST['foo'])
strip_tags($_POST['baz'])
another_function(strip_tags($_POST['bar']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use search and replace.

Search (\$_POST\['.*'\]) and replace by strip_tags(\1)

Comment: This would match strip_tags($_POST['diffentOnEachPage']), resulting in strip_tags(strip_tags$_POST['diffentOnEachPage'])